# Django - Multiple columns primary key

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I would like to implement multicolumns primary keys in django.

I've tried to implement an AutoSlugField() which concatenate my columns values(foreignkey/dates) ...

**models.py :**

```
class ProductProduction(models.Model):
    enterprise = models.ForeignKey('Enterprise')
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    count = models.IntegerField()
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=
    lambda instance: instance.enterprise.username + '-' + instance.product.name + '-' + str(date))
```

When I pass the following parameters :

```
 - 'Megacorp','robot','09/10/2010',5 => slug = 'Megacorp-robot-09/10/2010'
... the next time in pass the triplet, a new value has been inserted :
 - 'Megacorp','robot','09/10/2010',10 => slug = 'Megacorp-robot-09/10/2010' 
        => same slug value => insert ????
```

I tried to add `primary_key=True` parameter to the slug... but it creates new instance with a "-1" "-2" ... and NO update is made at all...

Did I miss something ?

Thanks,

Yoan

Comment: What is `AutoSlugField`?

Comment: @Daniel: I think something custom, like http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/#Current_Database_Model_Field_Extensions or http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/490/

Comment: A way to auto populate the slug field from another field, such as a title.  I believe James Bennett covered this in his book (Practical Django Projects), and it can also be found here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/490/

Comment: Neither of those custom `AutoSlugField` fields accept a lambda as a parameter. Until Yoan can show us the code for the field, we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation of the autoslugfield I used.

http://packages.python.org/django-autoslug/fields.html

Regards,

Yoan